# After configuring agens-graph, the following error occurred during the build

Tags: agens-graph

I want to install agens-graph.

An error occurred during the build.
1.build command

```
make world
```

The following are some of the errors.

```
make[2]: 디렉터리 '/home/bylee/install/agens-        graph/contrib/pg_freespacemap' 나감
make -C pg_hint_plan all
make[2]: 디렉터리 '/home/bylee/install/agens-graph/contrib/pg_hint_plan' 들어감
make[2]: pg_config: 명령을 찾지 못했음
make[2]: *** 타겟 'all'을(를) 만들 규칙이 없습니다.  멈춤.
make[2]: 디렉터리 '/home/bylee/install/agens-graph/contrib/pg_hint_plan' 나감
Makefile:96: 'all-pg_hint_plan-recurse' 타겟에 대한 명령이 실패했습니다
make[1]: *** [all-pg_hint_plan-recurse] 오류 2
make[1]: 디렉터리 '/home/bylee/install/agens-graph/contrib' 나감
GNUmakefile:19: 'world-contrib-recurse' 타겟에 대한 명령이 실패했습니다
make: *** [world-contrib-recurse] 오류 2
```

Can you help me with how to fix the error?

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be some problems with dependencies. To compile pg_hint_plan, pg_config must be built first. So run `make install` and then `make install-world`.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the pg_config file cannot be found as well as some missing dependencies.

You can first ensure through documentation what dependencies are missing and use the `make install` command to install them.

Similarly try locating the pg_config file and providing the correct path for it.